# Adding Access Database to Project in Visual Studio 2010 using c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

How i can Add an access database file to my project? i try to do by add-->add datasource and changing the name of data source in conncetion string but when i edit or delete or add data.. this changes does not save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

1. In Server Explorer, right-click Data Connections and click Add Connection.
2. In the Data Link Properties dialog box, click the Provider tab.
3. Click the Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider, then click Next.

   4.Click the ellipsis (...) button to browse to the Microsoft Access (.mdb) file you want to access.

   5.Type the User ID to use for authentication when you log on to the data source.
4. Type the Password to use for authentication when you log on to the data source.
   Click OK.

Comment: when i add, delete or edit data in my project in visual studio..it changes just when program is running..when i stop debug and i start again the change doesn't save..how to resolve

Comment: @Ghadir please add another question